# Customizing new Grails Spring Security Core Plugin login page

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I installed Grails Spring Security Core Plugin and it works great, but I can't find the gsp file for the login page. I want to change the login page to match my web theme. Anyone knows how to find the file ? I tried generate-views and also generate-all followed by User, UserRole, and Role domain classes but I didn't see the actual files. Also I can't find the login and logout controllers for the spring security core plugin in my project directories. Any idea what's going on ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're in the plugin itself, so it depends on where your plugins get installed. In 2.3 they'll be under `target/work/plugins`, and in earlier versions they'll be in the `.grails` folder which is in your home directory, so it'll be something like `$HOME/.grails/2.x.x/projects/<projectname>/plugins`

I like to keep things simple by deleting the `grails.project.class.dir`, `grails.project.test.class.dir`, and `grails.project.test.reports.dir` settings from `BuildConfig.groovy` and adding just

```
grails.project.work.dir = 'target'
```

so everything is in one place.

Comment: Thanks Burt, Great to hear the answer from the plugin owner :) I jumped to github and got a copy of your sample project to look at. I will follow your instruction here and hopefully it solves my problem. thanks!

Comment: I can't find any gsp file in target/work/plugins/spring-security-core*/src/templates.there are only 5 files:
Authority.groovy.template
PersistentLogin.groovy.template
Person.groovy.template
PersonAuthority.groovy.template
Requestmap.groovy.template. in such situation how I can change the default login page in grails?

Comment: They're not templates, they're real files. `LoginController.groovy` and `LogoutController.groovy` are in the plugin's `grails-app/controllers` folder and the GSPs are in `grails-app/views/login`. Copy one or more of those to the same location within your app's `grails-app` folder, creating the same folder structure, and yours will be used instead.

Comment: I find this files and copied them to my own project into package named grails.plugin.springsecurity but there is Error message: the type LoginController is already defined. Must I delete this files from my plugin path? I think I get this error because copied same named files

Comment: and wher I change the package name in my grails-app, the error disappear, but when I run the app and go to the login page, a get this error: No such property: SpringSecurityUtils for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity2.LoginController

Comment: I've seen the first issue in STS/GGTS, it's pretty annoying - I think it's not a problem in IntelliJ though. The 2nd problem is due to a missing import. There's no need to import SpringSecurityUtils when they're in the same package, but you need an import if they're not.